# Django Error: “AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1.”

Tags: python, django

I am running Python 2.7 and Django 1.5, using Eclipse Indigo. My project was working fine, until I stupidly played around a bit with my environment variables. At some point I began getting the following error:

```
AccessInit: hash collision: 3 for both 1 and 1.
```

Since then I have not been able to get the Django server working again. When attempting to load a url, the server throws an exception and shuts down. I tried copying the files into a new project, reconfiguring the env vars, whatever I could think of. It seems I have broken something. Does anyone know what this error might be related to? I have found it mentioned only in the context of PIL, which is not installed on my computer.

Comment: I have no idea about eclipse and making Django work with it. Sorry. But I'd recommend you to just use basic stuff. To load the server, just use the command line. I don't like Big full-of-tools IDEs, but it's just an opinion. Good luck with your problem.

Comment: What is the complete traceback that you get?

Answer (score 1):

Read [this blog post](http://jaredforsyth.com/blog/2010/apr/28/accessinit-hash-collision-3-both-1-and-1/)

TL; DR - Change your Python code to use the `from PIL import` syntax.

Comment: _" I have found it mentioned only in the context of PIL, which is not installed on my computer."_